# Flutter - auto_route _CustomNavigatorState error

Tags: flutter, dart, package, flutter-dependencies

I'm using the `auto_route` package in order to route my app and until 2 days ago everything worked just fine, until now.
For some reason, I'm getting the following error.

**SYSTEM:**

- **flutter**: 1.22
- **dart**: 2.10.0
- **auto_route**: ^0.6.7

**ERROR:**

```
../../.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/custom_navigator-0.3.0/lib/custom_navigator.dart:60:7: Error: The non-abstract class '_CustomNavigatorState' is missing implementations for these members:
 - WidgetsBindingObserver.didPushRouteInformation
Try to either
 - provide an implementation,
 - inherit an implementation from a superclass or mixin,
 - mark the class as abstract, or
 - provide a 'noSuchMethod' implementation.

class _CustomNavigatorState extends State<CustomNavigator>
      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/opt/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/binding.dart:122:16: Context: 'WidgetsBindingObserver.didPushRouteInformation' is defined here.
  Future<bool> didPushRouteInformation(RouteInformation routeInformation) {
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:device_simulator/device_simulator.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'Test.gr.dart' as r;
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

const bool debugEnableDeviceSimulator = true;

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
    builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder<r.Router>(
      router: r.Router(),
      builder: (context, extendedNav) => DeviceSimulator(
        enable: debugEnableDeviceSimulator,
        child:
            Scaffold(body: extendedNav, backgroundColor: Colors.red ),
      ),
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Also, I should mention, because of some update of flutter I guess, now I need to use `r.Router` instead of just `Router`.

**Test.dart**

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route_annotations.dart';

@MaterialAutoRouter(
  routes: <AutoRoute>[],
)
class $Router {}
```

And also if has any importance here it's the generated file

**Test.gr.dart**

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

// **************************************************************************
// AutoRouteGenerator
// **************************************************************************

// ignore_for_file: public_member_api_docs

import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';

class Routes {
  static const all = <String>{};
}

class Router extends RouterBase {
  @override
  List<RouteDef> get routes => _routes;
  final _routes = <RouteDef>[];
  @override
  Map<Type, AutoRouteFactory> get pagesMap => _pagesMap;
  final _pagesMap = <Type, AutoRouteFactory>{};
}
```

Do you have any idea what's going one here or how can I fix this? Or if I can't fix this, what can I use instead of the `auto_route` package which will offer me the same benefice?

Answer (score 0):

i solved this problem with add some function on library CustomNavigator :

```
Future<bool> didPushRouteInformation(RouteInformation routeInformation) {
    return didPushRoute(routeInformation.location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the place where the error is generating. Add the following function below there. I did the same and my problem is solved.

```
Future<bool> didPushRouteInformation(RouteInformation routeInformation) {
return didPushRoute(routeInformation.location);
}
```